# Condition does not work on the DragEnd event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable, drag

I learn JS less than a year.

I'm trying to write a condition for the drag event, so that the condition is taken into account when the 1st and last element in the array is determined and return null me. But for some reason, the condition is ignored, despite the fact that no errors are output to the console. Help please.

Function

```
const onDragEnd = (e) => {
    if (isActive)
        if (e.clientX >= window.innerWidth / 2)
            if (!cardsArray[0])
                setActive(active - 1)
            else return null

        else if (e.clientX <= window.innerWidth / 2)
            if (!cardsArray.length - 1)
                setActive(active + 1)
            else return null

    if (isPrev)
        setActive(active - 1)
    else if (isNext)
        setActive(active + 1)

}
```

Component

```
const cardsList = (
        <motion.div
            className={s.cardsList}
            style={{ transform: `translateX(${active * -50}%)` }}

        >
            {
                cardsArray.map(({ name, img, link, isDesktop }, i) => {

                    const isActive = i === active
                    const isPrev = i < active
                    const isNext = i > active

                    const handleClick = () => {
                        if (isActive)
                            history.push(link)             
                        if (isPrev)
                            setActive(active - 1)
                        else if (isNext)
                            setActive(active + 1)
                    }

                    const onDragEnd = (e) => {
                        if (isActive)
                            if (e.clientX >= window.innerWidth / 2)
                                if (!cardsArray[0])
                                    setActive(active - 1)
                                else return null

                            else if (e.clientX <= window.innerWidth / 2)
                                if (!cardsArray.length - 1)
                                    setActive(active + 1)
                                else return null

                        if (isPrev)
                            setActive(active - 1)
                        else if (isNext)
                            setActive(active + 1)

                    }

                    return (

                        <Card
                            key={i}
                            name={name}
                            img={img}
                            link={link}
                            {...{
                                i,
                                isActive,
                                isNext,
                                isPrev,
                                handleClick,
                                isDesktop,
                                onDragEnd
                            }}
                        />
                    )
                })
            }
        </motion.div>
    )
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thank you all for watching my problem, 
But I myself was able to find a solution:

I needed to supplement the condition with an exact indication of the iterator in the array

```
i != cardsArray[0]
```

and similarly in the second case

```
i != cardsArray.length - 1
```

That's all, folks! 
I hope helped someone else with self decision